# MongoError: FiledPath field names may notstart with '$'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm following the udemy cours by Brad Schiff- Learn JavaScript Full-Stack from Scratch, and on the section 7-7. Live Search Feature, I'm having problems with searching for posts. the problem happened after installation of axios.
Tried with the exact code from course but still se same error: **MongoError: FiledPath field names may notstart with '$'**
The code with the search feature:

```
import axios from "axios";

import DOMPurify from "dompurify";

export default class search {
  constructor() {
  this.injectHTML();
  this.headerSearchIcon = document.querySelector(".header-search-icon");
  this.overlay = document.querySelector(".search-overlay");
  this.closeIcon = document.querySelector(".close-live-search");
  this.inputField = document.querySelector("#live-search-field");
  this.resultsArea = document.querySelector(".live-search-results");
  this.loaderIcon = document.querySelector(".circle-loader");
  this.typingWaitTimer;
  this.previousValue = "";
  this.events();

  events() {
    this.inputField.addEventListener("keyup", () => this.keyPressHandler());
    this.closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => this.closeOverlay());
    this.headerSearchIcon.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.openOverlay();
    });
  }

  keyPressHandler() {
    let value = this.inputField.value;

    if (value == "") {
      clearTimeout(this.typingWaitTimer);
      this.hideLoaderIcon();
      this.hideResultsArea();
    }

    if (value != "" && value != this.previousValue) {
      clearTimeout(this.typingWaitTimer);
      this.showLoaderIcon();
      this.hideResultsArea();
      this.typingWaitTimer = setTimeout(() => this.sendRequest(), 750);
    }

    this.previousValue = value;
  }

  sendRequest() {
    axios
      .post("/search", { searchTerm: this.inputField.value })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.renderResultsHTML(response.data);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert("Hello, the request failed.");
      });
  }

}
```

---

The other code in Post.js file

```
Post.reusablePostQuery = function (uniqueOperations, visitorId) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    let aggOperations = uniqueOperations.concat([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "author",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "authorDocument",
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          title: 1,
          body: 1,
          createdDate: 1,
          authorId: "$author",
          author: { $arrayElemAt: ["$authorDocument", 0] },
        },
      },
    ]);

    let posts = await postsCollection.aggregate(aggOperations).toArray();

    // clean up author property in each post object
    posts = posts.map(function (post) {
      post.isVisitorOwner = post.authorId.equals(visitorId);
      post.authorId = undefined;

      post.author = {
        username: post.author.username,
        avatar: new User(post.author, true).avatar,
      };

      return post;
    });

    resolve(posts);
  });
};

Post.findSingleById = function (id, visitorId) {
  return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    if (typeof id != "string" || !ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
      reject();
      return;
    }

    let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery(
      [{ $match: { _id: new ObjectID(id) } }],
      visitorId
    );

    if (posts.length) {
      console.log(posts[0]);
      resolve(posts[0]);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};

Post.findByAuthorId = function (authorId) {
  return Post.reusablePostQuery([
    { $match: { author: authorId } },
    { $sort: { createdDate: -1 } },
  ]);
};


Post.search = function (searchTerm) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof searchTerm == "string") {
      //this. added
      let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery([
        { $match: { $text: { $search: searchTerm } } },
        { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
      ]);
      resolve(posts);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

---

the code in postController.js file

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {
  Post.search(req.body.searchTerm)
    .then((posts) => {
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      res.json([]);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue for days, and after looking out for different answers and quite some documentations I have figured out that you need to do a slight change in order to make this live search work.

the code for search function in Post.js file should be this

```js
Post.search = function (searchTerm) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof searchTerm == "string") {
      // sort by search score (or relevancy to search string)
      let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery([
        { $match: { $text: { $search: searchTerm } } },
        { $project: { _id: true,  "score": false } },
        { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } },
      ]);
      resolve(posts);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

Try this and It will work fine..